# How to set the countplot order

Tags: python, seaborn, countplot

I am trying to determine the order of my countplot.
This is the code I wrote:

```
df['new salery'].sort_values()
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(8,6)})
sns.countplot(x='new salery',data=df,palette='viridis')
```

the plot I got is:
[image: CountPlot]

What I am trying to do is to put this order -

> Low salary, Medium Salary -, Medium Salary, Medium Salary +, High
>   Salary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make the column an ordered `Categorical`. From this, `seaborn` automatically follows the order:

```
df['new salery'] = pd.Categorical(df['new salery'], 
  categories=['light', 'medium-', 'medium', 'medium+', 'large'], ordered=True)
sns.countplot(x='new salery', data=df, palette='viridis')
```

Alternatively, if you only want to do it for the plot, you can also use the `order`-keyword within the function:

```
sns.countplot(x='new salery',data=df,palette='viridis', 
              order=['light', 'medium-', 'medium', 'medium+', 'large'])
```

[image: Ordered countplot]